# what database support configurations to make some fields/column cannot be updated and forbid record deletion?

Tags: database, database-design

as the title, what database support configurations **to make some fields/column cannot be updated and forbid record deletion?**

concretely, is there any database or database usage support the function that I can config some fields/column cannot be updated, and records in database cannot be deleted.

I know this can be done by upper code logic, however, we only allow to do it at database level.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no relational database engine that forbids row deletion.  You can put some or all of your database tables on a WORM (write once, read many) drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed, mysql trigger can satisfy my requirements.

more info about mysql trigger can refer to this [usecase](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mysql-trigger).